# Custom Modal in Create/Edit forms

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to create a custom modal instead of the 'Element is created' at the bottom of the screen. How should I create a custom modal which says 'Element is created' and if it is a failure, mention the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply another label using the translations or you can create a custom Admin `Layout` (use the layout prop) and replace the current `Notification` component.